# Can I use echo to return some data from a PHP Curl call?

Tags: php, post, echo

I am sending a POST request via CURL from a script on server1 to a webpage on server2.

Server2 processes the POST data and returns a result to server1.

I'm using echo to return the result even though nothing will be output to the browser or screen. Most resources I've found for echo say that it is to be used to output to browser or screen - the manual just says "echo - output one or more strings".

So is using echo OK in this situation and/or is there a better way?

Here is code from the webpage that processes the script:

```
if (!empty($_POST["postvar1"])) {
        $message = 'This is your message:"'.$_POST["postvar1"].'"';
        echo $message;
}

//do something else - e.g. log details
```

For anyone who wants to know - here is the script on server1 which sends and receives the POST via curl:

```
function send_message($url, $post){

    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url ); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}

//send message
$post = array('postvar1' => 'Hello World!');
$url = 'https://example.com/receive-message.php';
$response = send_message($url, $post);


//process response
if (!empty($response)) {
    //do something - e.g. add to database
}
```

Comment: use `var_dump` for the request received, `var_dump($response)`

Comment: What to do with the response was not the question. It was about the best way to generate the response: echo or something else?

Comment: Generate _what_ response? You said nothing will be output on the screen, so _whom_ do you want to give a response in the first place?

Comment: Looks like his second script is for getting + sending the response. Looks like the question was worded incorrectly as the OP very clearly wants a response.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code or reasons why it wouldn't work, I feel like this question is maybe a code review question?

Comment: If i understand well, the real question is just, can I use `echo` to return some data from a Curl call ?

Comment: And the answer to that is, sure, why the hell not ? :D Case closed?

Comment: I think so :) Well @Ryan you can also use `print` or whatever you like, just keep in mind that what you are currently doing is totally correct

Comment: `print` appends data to the output stream which is independent of the type of client connected to it so you don't need to distinguish between a browser or a script client. One thing I'd recommend is to provide an answer on Server2 that the client (Server1) can interpret to find out if complete data has been returned. Options would be to send an XML or JSON structure that can checked for completeness.